# divergence statement for redundant threads

Tags: c, cuda

I have a 400x900 matrix which means 360,000 elements. Number of threads in a block is 1024. Number of blocks (square arrangement) is 352 which means totally 360,448 threads. So, 448 threads will do nothing assuming a thread is assigned to each element. I have read about divergence branches and understood but here I do not understand what the divergence statement and the code should be?

Comment: What is a "divergence statement"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since threads are grouped into blocks in CUDA, we often use a little more threads than the actual size of the data to do the work in parallel. In this case, we need a branch to ensure that only those threads that are assigned with the data will work, and other threads just wait and do nothing.

The following post shows how to calculate AXPY using CUDA. You will find that although the total number of threads is always a multiple of 256, the kernel can work on the vectors of arbitrary length `N`. The code `if (i < n) {...}` ensures that those extra threads will do nothing.

https://developer.nvidia.com/content/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c